# Adding items to Codeigniter Cart through controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I'm trying to work with Codeigniter's cart. 
I've got a list of available products from my model. However, when I try to add it to cart nothing is being added. I suspect it's because I'm not returning products correctly.

Here's my model:

```
  function getHolidayTVProducts()  {
    return array(
        'TVHOL_1000' => array('id' => 'TVHOL_1000', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 148.50, 'name' => '1,000 to 20,000 - $148.50 USD'),
        'TVHOL_20000' => array('id' => 'TVHOL_20000', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 178.50, 'name' => '20,000 to 30,000 - $178.50 USD'),
        'TVHOL_30000' => array('id' => 'TVHOL_30000', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 208.50, 'name' => '30,000 to 40,000 - $208.50 USD'),
        'TVHOL_40000' => array('id' => 'TVHOL_40000', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 238.50, 'name' => '40,000 to 50,000 - $238.50 USD'),
        'TVHOL_50000' => array('id' => 'TVHOL_50000', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 268.50, 'name' => '50,000 to 60,000 - $268.50 USD'),
        'TVHOL_60000' => array('id' => 'TVHOL_60000', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 298.50, 'name' => '60,000 to 70,000 - $298.50 USD'),
        'TVHOL_70000' => array('id' => 'TVHOL_70000', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 0, 'name' => 'Over 70,000 - Please call')
    );
}

// Function returns an array containing a specific product ID
function getHolidayTVProduct($productID) {
    $array = $this->getHolidayTVProducts();
    return $array[$productID];
}
```

Getting the products doesn't seem to be a problem. This is my controller:

```
        $holiday_products = $this->products->getHolidayTVProducts();
    $holiday_tv_available_products = array('Select Your Circulation'); //placeholder text
    foreach ($holiday_products as $key => $item) {
        $holiday_tv_available_products[$key] = $item['name'];
    }
    $data['products_TVHoliday'] = $holiday_tv_available_products;

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {           
        $this->load->view('templates/header.php', $header);
        $this->load->view('printmedia/holiday', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/modal.php');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
    }

    else { 
        $selected_product = $this->products->getHolidayTVProduct($this->input->post('products_TVHoliday'));
        echo $selected_product;
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        $products_ID = $this->products->getHolidayTVProduct($this->input->post('products_TVHoliday'));
        $selected_product = $products_ID;
        $this->cart->insert($selected_product);
```

From my view.

```
              <?php echo form_open('printmedia/themed/holiday-tv'); ?>
              <?php echo form_dropdown('products_TVHoliday', $products_TVHoliday, '', 'class="span6"'); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="winterOrder" class="row-fluid">
                <p><!--Place Special Ordering form here  --></p>
            </div>                
            <div class="row-fluid">
              <?php echo form_submit('processorder', 'Process Order', 'class="btn btn-inverse"');?>
              <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: What exactly does `$select_product` contain ?

Comment: When echo, it's Array. print_r is Array ( [id] => TVHOL_1000 [qty] => 1 [price] => 148.5 [name] => 1,000 to 20,000 - $148.50 USD )

I think the issue is in here but I'm not sure how to handle it from this point.

Comment: Try to print_r this `$this->cart->contents();`

Comment: Brings back Array ( )

Comment: Btw try to add `echo "2nd cond";` to this part of code: `if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {`

Comment: It echoes. I think I'm missing a step with the $select_product, $selected_product doesn't seem to passing the array to $this->insert->cart.

Comment: Try to print_r the `$selected_product` at the 2nd condition

Comment: Prints out Array ( [id] => TVHOL_1000 [qty] => 1 [price] => 148.5 [name] => 1,000 to 20,000 - $148.50 USD )

Comment: Lol...Have you ever loaded the cart library ? `$this->load->library('cart');`

Comment: lol, yes. autoloaded. I can add to cart if I create an array for the product in the view and trigger cart insert with a link

Comment: Ok another: print_r this: `$products_ID;`

Comment: Printed two arrays? Array ( [id] => TVHOL_20000 [qty] => 1 [price] => 178.5 [name] => 20,000 to 30,000 - $178.50 USD ) Array ( [id] => TVHOL_20000 [qty] => 1 [price] => 178.5 [name] => 20,000 to 30,000 - $178.50 USD )

Comment: Actually, it printed $selected_product and $products_id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34703/discussion-between-deiform-and-lmacdonell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in special characters in name of product:

```
50,000 to 60,000 - $268.50 USD
```

Adding to card worked after deleting dolar sign and comma.

```
50 000 to 60 000 - 268.50 USD
```